# Run thousands of simple scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to run a simple python script in ~6500 directories. The easiest, and least efficient way is to do:

```
for d in *_directorynumber; do (cd "$d" && cp ../script.py . && python ./script.py );done
```

This obviously takes forever. Instead, I try to run in parallel:

```
task(){
   cd "$d" && python ./script.py . 
}
```

Then run this task as such:

```
for d in *_directorynumber; do 
  task "$d" &
done
```

After ~500 runs or so, I get the following error:

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Is there another way to parallelize?

Comment: `parallel` or `xargs -P` (Depending on versions etc.) see e.g. the questions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel

Comment: You are running too many processes. Perhaps you need to increase `nproc`, but it is more likely that you just have to increase the user's `ulimit`.

Comment: Why would you copy the script each time? Is that necessary for some reason? Surely a symlnk would be enough even if the script required the data to be in the same directory.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have your script picking the folders, and running stuff in parallel inside a single script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of processes. You can display it with the command `ulimit -u`. You may be able to increase it with the same commands. If it is a shared machine, you probably don't have the privileges to do this.

Running 6500 processes in parallel is most likely a bad idea.

- You need RAM for 6500 processes.
- If your task is CPU bound, it will be slower, because it needs much more context switches.
- If your task is I/O bound, having 6500 processes access different directories will also make it slower.

Your task may benefit from some parallel processes, but you should limit it to a small multiple of the number of CPU cores you have.

Comment: Linux is pretty efficient at context switches. I just tested running 1000 procs in parallel on a CPU with 4 CPU threads. The difference to running 4 procs in parallel was minimal (< 1%). The other arguments are valid, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel 'cd {} && cp ../script.py . && python ./script.py' :::  *_directorynumber
```

This will run one `script.py` per CPU thread until all are done.

If `script.py` is not CPU bound you can adjust the number of jobs with `--jobs`:

- `--jobs 10` run exactly 10 in parallel
- `--jobs 200%` run 2x CPU threads in parallel
- `--jobs 0` run as many as you can until you hit a limit (such as: `-bash: fork: retry: No child processes`) then stay below that limit.